# the password and username doesnt work?

Tags: android, if-statement, onclick, passwords

I guess I don't understand why this isn't working the logcat doesn't tell me anything and when i put in the onclick method just the startactivity intent it works just fine. When I add the if statement it wont go to the other activity.I checked that i was typing it in correctly too. Here's the code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    String user;
    String password;
    String admin ="admin";
    String pass ="lpt";
    EditText username;
    EditText passcode;
    Button login;
    Intent main = new Intent("android.intent.action.CONTROLS");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    passcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            user = username.getText().toString();
            password = passcode.getText().toString();
            if(user==admin && password == pass){
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CONTROLS"));
            }
            }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: i think == is if the two are pointing at the same object String.equals() is what you should use, i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please dont use `==` for string comparison use `equals` or  `equalsIgnoreCase` instead

```
if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("pass")
```